# Export HTML/JS/CSS to PDF using django-wkhtmltopdf

Tags: django, django-views, wkhtmltopdf

Goal: export a HTML/CSS/JS page to PDF. This page include charts created using the Rgraph library. When I use wkhtmltopdf from the command line, it works perfect. The problem arise when I try to use the django-wkhtmltopdf, because it does not include the javascript libraries neither the css ones. So, it renders a white unformatted pdf page.

The Class Based View that I'm using is this one:

```
class ResumenPDFView(DetailView):

    template_name = 'planes/plan_resumen_pdf.html'
    model = Plan

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context['plan'] = self.get_object()

        response = PDFTemplateResponse(
            request=request,
            template=self.template_name,
            filename=str(self.context['plan'].anio) + "-" + str(self.context['plan'].temporada.nombre) + ".pdf",
            context=self.context,
            show_content_in_browser=False,
            cmd_options={'margin-top': 10, }
        )
        return response
```

And what I'm getting is something like this: http://s7.postimg.org/99zmxelkr/SS2_PDF.png

If I remove the get function of the CBV, like this:

```
class ResumenPDFView(DetailView):

    template_name = 'planes/plan_resumen_pdf.html'
    model = Plan
```

This is the HTML version of the page: http://s21.postimg.org/xwib1s5hz/SS1.png

So, as you can see, It seems related to a problem of not including the JS/CSS libraries.

Finally, like I said before, if I use wkhtmltopdf from the command line on the HTML version, it works perfect.

Can I, somehow, pass the result of the command line wkhtmltopdf execution to the user, without using the django-wkhtmltopdf package?